# Is there a one word to ask politely about those who born and grew up in the States?

Tags: synonyms

When travelling in the UK or Europe and meeting friends, I used to ask a question: "Are you a native British / French / ...", until I came to America, I figured out that cannot ask this question in the same way of "native American"

So, is there still a one-word (or simple enough phrase) to ask politely, to describe those who born and grew up in the States? Or probably lived his/her whole life in the States.

To imply something to be known by only those who stayed long enough in the States, because my following question might be something like "when in the 90s, ..." / "when you were in high school, did you know ...", before that, I want to confirm the person is not a visitor in the States, nor a new immigrant who moved to the States for only a few years and might know very little.

Comment: Are you native to the United States / US?

Comment: "Are you originally from the US?"

Comment: One should bear in mind that some people may perceive the question itself as impolite, **regardless of how it is formulated**, if the context does not provide sufficient justification for it.

Comment: I prefer to ask "Where are you from?" which doesn't load the question, or make any suppositions, and the answer can be surprising. If (in UK) I think someone may be from, say, Japan and they answer "I am from Manchester" I take that at face value: that is what they want to tell me. I leave any more until we know each other a little better.

Comment: I actually know a person, of "Chinese" (East Asian) ethnicity, who was born, not in Manchester, but in Ashton-under-Lyne, and she used to be so tired of people saying "Yes, but where are you _really_ from?". Asking the question is itself racist.

Comment: @HotLicks: "Brooklyn" in this case would be better than "the US." It is aesthetically wrong to ask someone IN the U.S. whether they're FROM the U.S., and grammatically unsound, too.

Comment: @Ricky - How is it "grammatically unsound"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a different StackExchange, probably the Interpersonal Skills one.

Comment: @linguisticturn: Have you done any other positive things today?

Comment: It should be noted that in written materials (at least if they are written by careful writers or edited by competent copyeditors), *native American* has a different meaning from *Native American*.

Comment: @Ricky Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. (BTW, I wasn't among those who downvoted you.)

Comment: Are you a local?

Answer (score -3):

The single question you need to ask is "Are you and American?"

An American is one who, if not born here comes here and accedes to the rules to be a citizen, particularly to be agreeable to the rules and regulations and disowning previous commitments. Those are the only requirements.

The term "Native American" is the creation of the Federal Government. It is not resented by those Native Americans since it is a good term to group their many tribes as distinct from the Westerners who have come ashore and keep coming.

Comment: This does not distinguish the America-born American from the naturalised American, which is the point of OP's question.

Comment: The point of being an American is that there *is* no difference. The "success" of the following answer shows that the rating is not of the answer but of the reality.

Answer (score -5):

"Sir, you were born in this country, I take it?"

"Ma'am, you're an American born and raised, is that correct?"

"Pardon me, miss. Are you a native of this country?"

Comment: All of those would have to be used with care, as they would easily be taken as insulting (in that they can be seen as implying that those who are not native are lesser).

Comment: I certainly would not ask any of those questions of a stranger – people you call Sir, Ma'am or Miss.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Funny. Primo: why don't you come up with your own, utterly polite version that one could use carelessly? I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @WeatherVane: How about just "Yo!" Instead of Sir, Ma'am, or Miss. Would that be all right?